# How does offset padding gets applied to child element from parent iteslf

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I am learning bootstrap and I want to know how does the `offset` set on the 
 parent element gets applied to the child elements and what is its significance over applying the styles directly to the child element? I saw scenario 1 type of bootstrap set up in one of the popular website.

Scenario 1:

```
<div class = "footer-offset-padding navbar-offset-padding">
  <div class="navbar">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .navbar-offset-padding  {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
   .footer-offset-padding   {
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

Scenario 2:

```
<div class = "nothing">
  <div class="navbar navbar-offset-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="footer footer-offset-padding">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-offset-padding  {
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-offset-padding{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

As a beginner, if I wanted padding I would have followed an approach similar to Scenario 2. I am not able to understand, how does first scenario works. Why don't we add the padding **"Directly to the Element Itself (Footer and Header in this case)"**. Is there some other benefit we get when applying Scenario 1. Please guide me a little. I am not even sure why/how does Scenario 1 even works?

Comment: Isn't scenario 1 meant for fixed navbar and footer, where the padding in the parent div serves as a placeholder for the screen space those bars take up.

Comment: I am a beginner sir, so I don't know what's going on here..